# How to stop jquery Cycle 2 on certain slide number?

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle2

I have Cycle2 carousel on auto play. Does someone know how to stop Cycle2 carousel on certain slide?

Using 
$('.cycle-slideshow').on('cycle-update-view', function (e, optionHash, slideOptionsHash, currentSlideEl) {
    var caption = (optionHash.currSlide + 1) ;
      //alert(optionHash.currSlide);

```
     if(optionHash.currSlide == 3){
          $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('stop');

     }

    });
});
```

make  carousel jump on slide 3 instead of slide on side # 3 and stop.

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Solved it by doing this:if(optionHash.currSlide > 2){
              $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('pause');

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :
$( document ).ready(function() {

$('.cycle-slideshow').on('cycle-update-view', function (e, optionHash, slideOptionsHash, currentSlideEl) {
    var caption = (optionHash.currSlide + 1) //+ ' of ' + optionHash.slideCount;
      //alert(optionHash.currSlide);

```
     if(optionHash.currSlide > 2){
          $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('pause');
     //do something else
     }

    });
```

});